# Ubuntu on Micromax Funbook Pro With Cortex A8 processor

Tags: tablet

I am using Micomax Funbook Pro Tab with comes with Cortex A8 (1.2GHz) processor and 1GB RAM. It runs Android 4.0 Scecream Sandwich. I am willing to use Ubuntu on it. Is there anyway I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

An ubuntu image for this tablet isn't available probably. Installing ubuntu on x86 arch (All PC processor) isn't same as these tablets which are based on ARM architecture. You need special imanges. Currently ubuntu image is only provided for Nexus 7 tablet.

However, Installing ubuntu as virtual system and using it via VNC is pretty easy.

- First you need to root your device (rooting voids warranty, be careful to review other side effects that may happen including a complete brick)

  This can help - [Rooting guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1906229)

  - Use Complete [Linux Installer app](http://linuxonandroid.org/what-is-linuxonandroid/) & andriod VNC.

  **[A complete step by step tutorial can be found here](http://funbook.gizmolord.com/tutorial-how-to-run-linux-in-micromax-funbook/)**

<sub>**I don't have this device, neither I did any tests.** This answer is based on search on internet.
You won't get much help in this Q&A site.Because ubuntu doesn't support your tablet. It is better to head for XDA dev forum.</sub>